# what is the meaning of uneasy accuracy?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What does uneasy mean in the following context?

```
The robot can emulate the movement of an actual finger with uneasy accuracy.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look earlier in the piece you quoted from (you should have given the source).

[Creepy Detached Finger for Your Phone](https://curiosity.com/topics/check-out-this-creepy-detached-finger-for-your-phone-curiosity/)

> **There's something very uncanny valley** about the way that it moves — you know that it isn't real, but because of the five precise motors
>   contained in the tiny device, it can emulate the movement of an actual
>   finger with uneasy accuracy.

The accuracy with which the robot finger moves makes the viewer feel uneasy, because it seems nearly like a real finger belonging to a person. "Uncanny valley" is a slang expression describing a common unsettling feeling people experience when robot devices or simulations closely resemble humans in many respects but are not quite convincingly realistic.

The adjective 'uneasy' seems to be applied to the accuracy of movement of the robot finger, but it actually describes the feeling experienced by the viewer. Similarly, a car with worn steering and suspension might be said to give an uneasy or nervous ride - the unease or nervousness is felt by the people in the car.

Comment: So when we use uneasy accuracy it means that we are talking about high degree of accuracy?

Comment: We are talking about accuracy **that makes people feel uneasy**, because they do not expect human-like behaviour from a machine.